# Remove all Mac generated files '._' with bash

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm trying to find the command to delete recursively all Apple Mac generated files such as '._' from the drive. So far I have:

```
find . -name '._*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

however it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, this is off-topic. Try superuser.stackexchange.com

Comment: How is this off topic? Isn't ssh covered here - I've seen several posts for ssh, but none explaining how to achieve the above.

Comment: They might have been old questions. Since StackOverflow launched, lots of StackExchanges have sprung up to fill specialisms. Those questions might have appeared before that StackExchange site existed.

Comment: (I know how frustrating it is to have something marked off-topic, but  it needs a number of votes from the community to confirm it so it's nothing personal.)

Comment: What do you observe?

Comment: That find command should work fine.  If you're seeing warnings/errors like `find: './._': No such file or directory`, try running this instead: `find . -depth -name '._*' -exec rm -rf {} \;` to do a depth-first traversal, deleting matching items in subdirectories before trying to delete the directories themselves.

Comment: what error are you see? and for that matter what "Apple Mac" generated files are you seeing that start with `._` ?

Answer (score 34):

There's now a better way!

See `man dot_clean` since OS X 10.5.

`dot_clean -n .` will not just delete the dot underbar files in and below the current directory, it'll merge their information into the parent file if it's not already there (and I infer that you want `-n` to also delete the dot underbar file if there is no matching native file).

Answer (score 4):

Using the dot as first argument starts in the directory you are currently in.

If you want to find **all** files beginning with ._ you should use the slash as first parameter so that find starts at the root-directory.

And as some of these files will not be owned by you you might like to use the suso command also.

So the complete command looks like this:

```
sudo find / -name "._*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

At least for me that always does the trick. Ommiting the -exec part will simply list all files so you might run this first to see whether all files are found you expect

Answer (score 4):

I know: this post is obsolete. Anyway I write here because is the first I found! I had the same problem with a Dropbox account that I used on mac osx, moved now on Windows / Linux Ubuntu.
Using bash (mine is the Cygwin64 bash), I typed inside my Dropbox folder:

```
find . -regex '.+/\._.+' -exec rm {} \;
```

Note that -rf was removed from above solutions. '._' are supposed to be only files, so do not add too many powers to rm command! ;)

Answer (score 0):

find . ( -name '._*' ) -exec rm {} -rf \;
should work

I don't know if it's different in OSX compared to bash.

Comment: Macs run Bash and certainly have `find` although I think it's a bit out of date. The man page says 2008, but I'm sure it'll be sufficiently up to date.

Answer (score 0):

First find the files from current folder with type and name pattern then exec command to remove it:

```
find ./ -type f -name "._*" -exec rm -r {} \;
```

I had same issue. this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm using XAMPP LAMPP and this happens most of the time a virtual drive

I open a terminal window at the root of any folder on LAMPP server / htdocs and just type:

```
dot_clean anyfoldername
```

It's recursive, so simple, I hope it helps.