# remove all mac `._` files on Linux NAS?

Tags: linux, nas

I'm trying to remove all the hidden mac spam files off my old NAS box (qnap ts209). I tried following [Remove all Mac generated files '._' with bash](https://superuser.com/questions/522149/remove-all-mac-generated-files-with-bash) but the find command on my NAS does not include the `-exec` option.

```
# [/share/Qweb] # find -name "._*" -exec rm -rf {} \;

Usage: find [PATH...] [EXPRESSION]

Search for files in a directory hierarchy.  The default PATH is
the current directory; default EXPRESSION is '-print'

EXPRESSION may consist of:
        -follow         Dereference symbolic links.
        -name PATTERN   File name (leading directories removed) matches PATTERN.
        -print          Print (default and assumed).

        -type X         Filetype matches X (where X is one of: f,d,l,b,c,...)
        -perm PERMS     Permissions match any of (+NNN); all of (-NNN);
                        or exactly (NNN)
        -mtime TIME     Modified time is greater than (+N); less than (-N);
                        or exactly (N) days

[/share/Qweb] #
```

Here's some info about my box:

```
[/share/Qweb] # man find
-sh: man: command not found
[/share/Qweb] # cat /etc/*-release
cat: /etc/*-release: No such file or directory
[/share/Qweb] # lsb_release
-sh: lsb_release: command not found
[/share/Qweb] # cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.12.6-arm1 (root@NasARM4) (gcc version 3.4.4 (release) (CodeSourcery ARM 2005q3-2)) #2 Sun Sep 18 02:09:29 CST 2011
[/share/Qweb] # uname -a
Linux QNAP 2.6.12.6-arm1 #2 Sun Sep 18 02:09:29 CST 2011 armv5tejl unknown
[/share/Qweb] # uname -mrs
Linux 2.6.12.6-arm1 armv5tejl
```

I have no idea how to pipe from find into rm, perhaps it's possible, i got pretty confused searching SU for answers that don't involve `-exec` . (Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11191868/1238884 suggests piping to RM isn't an option; damn, I don't have the `-delete` option either.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing the PATH argument the message is asking for, i.e., something like

```
find . -name "._*" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Note the `.` here. If not from the current directory down, replace by the starting path.

If you have `xargs(1)`, you might use that one so each invocaton of `rm(1)` processes several files at once:

```
find . -name "._*" | xargs rm
```

Be careful, do a dry run calling e.g. just `echo(1)` to make sure nothing untoward will happen.

Comment: `xargs` works, thanks a bunch! (also echo, but then `find . -name "._*" -print` does as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called "del_apple_files.py" (or similar), inside of it paste this:

```
#!/bin/env python

import os
import fnmatch 

def purge(dir, pattern):
   for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir):     
       for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, pattern):
           match = os.path.join(root, filename)        
           print(str(match))     
           os.remove(match)                  

dir = '/PATH/TO/SHARED/FOLDERS/ROOT'
pattern = '._*'

purge(dir, pattern)
```

Copy the file to your NAS box, SSH into it and run the file as an admin user with access permissions throughout your shared folders:

```
python /PATH/TO/del_apple_file.py
```

You can also schedule a cronjob for it, it will only delete files and will leave folders behind...

Enjoy! ;)