# Can I archive Windows and Mac files in the same WinRar file?

Tags: windows, windows-10, winrar

I have no real experience of Apple / Mac OS files so forgive me if this is a bit of a noob question but it is directly connected to Windows 10.

I use Windows 10 and winRar V5.91

I have a need to archive 16gb of Windows .wav & Apple OS ._wav files stored in several windows folders.

For every Windows .wav there is a copy of it as a Apple OS ._wav file and they all reside in the same windows folder.

My question is can I safely place both the windows and OS files, the Windows .wav & Apple OS ._wav files, in the same archive?

My current thinking is to archive the windows folder that contains both.

Comment: [Why are files beginning with "._" created when I copy or back up files to an external storage device?](https://kb.synology.com/en-ro/DSM/tutorial/Why_are_dot_underscore_files_created#:~:text=When%20you%20back%20up%20or,paste%20a%20file%20called%20%22FILE.) [I simply delete the "`._`" files](https://superuser.com/questions/522149/remove-all-mac-generated-files-with-bash)

Comment: Should be fine. Those are known as dotfiles and they are considered cruft; not necessary macOS files.